# Branch io Webhook not disclosing Facebook App Install Campaign Data

Tags: branch.io

We are trying to install branch to find out which user saw which ad to install our app.

We are running Facebook App Install Campaigns.

In the webhook we are getting all our campaign and ad level data as "undisclosed"

Looking for a solution to this.

Below is how the webhook payload looks like.

```
    last_attributed_touch_data      {21}
$3p :   undisclosed
~advertising_partner_name   :   undisclosed
+click_timestamp    :   undisclosed
~secondary_publisher    :   undisclosed
~ad_name    :   undisclosed
~ad_set_id  :   undisclosed
+via_features   :   undisclosed
~feature    :   undisclosed
~campaign_id    :   undisclosed
~ad_set_name    :   undisclosed
~ad_id  :   undisclosed
~advertising_account_id :   undisclosed
~advertising_partner_id :   undisclosed
~ad_objective_name  :   undisclosed
~creative_id    :   undisclosed
~campaign   :   undisclosed
~channel    :   undisclosed
~creative_name  :   undisclosed
$fb_data_terms_not_signed   :   undisclosed
~is_mobile_data_terms_signed    :   undisclosed
~tune_publisher_name    :   undisclosed
```

We can see in the branch analytics that these data are avaialble. We are able to see how many people came from which ads.

We have set up a regular webhook to be triggered with the install event occurs, with the campaign level data.

Answer (score 0):

this is expected as listed [here](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-ads-overview#facebooks-advanced-mobile-measurement-agreement)

> On October 29th, 2021 Facebook deprecated the AMM (Advanced Mobile
> Measurement) program, resulting in click and impression log-level data
> no longer available to export. Advertisers that incorporate installs
> into their attribution model can still measure the aggregate number of
> view-through and click-through installs from Facebook in Ads Manager
> and in their Branch dashboard to the ad ID level of granularity.

Comment: Thanks Ivin, 

I have also implemented https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-install-referrer. 

I am still seeing no difference in the data being sent, as all data is still undisclosed. Would you happen to know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

A Branchster here -

This is expected behavior based on Meta's Policies. In short, the log-level data will show as undisclosed when you try to export the data through webhooks or other Export APIs.

While Facebook Install Referrer is a workaround please note that it is only specific to Android Installs coming through Play Store.

You can read more about this [here](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-ads-overview#data-limitations)